#  GridView1: How to save the selected value from the dropdownlist and make it visible

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

- I have a dropdownlist.

  - A column called id has the control dropdownlist ( I've changed the
    textbox into a dropdownlist).
  - The dropdownlist is containing 2 values : Yes/No .

On gridview row update I want to save the value choosed in the dropdownlist . how can I do that?
Also,how can I make the value choosed in the dropdown visible in the gridview.

thans

Comment: try to use FindControl method of gridview

Comment: eh I'm not so advanced can you bring an example please? thank you

Comment: god I'm trying since 3 days ago to find a way to do this.:(

Comment: the code is currently the humpy's code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
   protected void GridViewRowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
          var rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
          var row = GridView.Rows[rowIndex];
          var ddl = row.FindControl("YOURDROPDOWN") as DropDownList;
          if(ddl != null)
          var value = ddl.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Comment: yep i tested and I can get the value but how can i set it to the dropdown so it will be always the value selected until I change it.? thank you , yey I'm close to what I wanted xd

Comment: its not clear what you try to achieve, do you need to set the value to dropdown from existing values?? (i mean YES or NO)??

Comment: ok then just set the **selected index** for the dropdown. **eg.ddl.SelectedIndex = 1;**

Comment: where you bind data to dropdown?

Comment: I'm not inding data to dropdown , it has 2 fixed values , if you mean where I choose the values , I choose them in the edit mode

Comment: but I want if I close the page , the values to be saved there